# Setting default parameters to a function from a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to set parameters to a function from an arbitary dictionary. For example, if I have

```py
d = {"a": 5, "b": 8}
```

I would want to define a function like this

```py
def f(a = 5, b = 8) :
    print(a, b)
```

but whitout specifying the arguments , so, ultimately, I would want to do something like

```py
def f(**d): 
    print(a,b)
```

but obviousely this wouldn't work, it just works when we call the function and not when it's defined, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `print(d.get('a'), d.get('b'))`

Comment: What is it you expect to happen when the function is defined, and what is happening instead?

Comment: I expect the function to be defined as if I gave it optional parameters, so if I do f(a = 1) it prints out 3, 8 and if I do f(), it would print out 5, 8

Comment: You mean you want the values to be set only if you specify both values else not and just print default values?

Answer (score 3):

You can use both defaults and **kwargs in the function:

```
> def f(a=5, b=7, **kwargs):
>     print(a, b)

> f()
5, 7

> f(1, 2)
1, 2

> f(**{'a':20, 'b': 40})
20, 40

> f(**{'a':20})
20, 7

> f(a=300, **{'b':100})
300, 100

> # Okay
> f(3, **{'b':20})
3, 20

> # Not Okay
> f(3, **{'a':20})
TypeError: f() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an arbitrary set of keyword arguments to a function by using the `**` (dict unpacking) operator on a dict, and you can define a function to process a set of such keyword arguments by using the same operator. Once inside the function, the variable specified in the definition behaves like a `dict`. Example:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs["a"], kwargs["b"])

d = {"a": 5, "b": 8}
f(**d)
f(a=5, b=8)  # this behaves the same way
```

It's also generally safer to use the `.get()` function when dealing with a `**kwargs` dict, since that lets you set a default value in case the given key wasn't passed as a variable. For example:

```
def f(**kwargs):
    a = kwargs.get('a', 5)
    b = kwargs.get('b', 8)
    print(a, b)

f(a=9, b=13)  # prints 9 13
f()           # prints 5 8
```

Comment: The things is I need the function to prints out the values even thought I don't give it any parameters , so f() would print out 5, 8

Comment: @AyoubZAROU ...yes, that's what my second example does. If you want, you can store a dict `d` somewhere else in your program and use it to inform what your default values should be, e.g. `a = kwargs.get('a', d['a'])`

Comment: oh ok it's not exactly what I was looking for , but I guess this solves my problem too

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I found a way to do what I first intended

```py
d = {"a": 5, "b": 8}
def f(**kwargs) : 
   c = d.copy()
   c.update(kwargs)
   print(c["a"], c["b"])
```

This way I don't have to set the arguments one by one inside a function (I have a very large dictionary on the actual problem I'm trying to slove), and I don't have to set arguments to the function when defined